# Initiate a deep learning model on application level in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have deployed a model on web but for each call from user application creates a new instance an load it into memory, which hits memory limit when a few users are using application at the same time. A solution I found is that model has to be initialized at application level rather than function level and for that I'll have to create [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309042/python-how-to-set-global-variables-in-flask). There is another option [Application Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/). The question is which one is suitable for my problem here. I am initializing model in different file and then importing it in `app.py` file where there are flask functions to interact with user. If I have to use global variable, do I need to initialize model with global variable or use it where I am import that model?

Comment: Can't you just disable thread mode: `app.run(threaded=False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track and the methods you listed are valid - depending on usecase one might be better than the other. As a concept you need to use the [Singleton pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html).

Singleton Pattern will ensure that at any given point only one instance of the class/function exits hence keeping your memory consumption in check. For doing so you will need to ensure that the function is stateless, i.e. given a set of input parameters, it should give the output without altering the output for a different request.

There are many threads on singleton in Flask, I won't repeat it here. Here's a starting point
[How to create a singleton object in Flask micro framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477038/how-to-create-a-singleton-object-in-flask-micro-framework)